# PYTHON. можно ли ввести два символа в keyboard.wait()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyboard

переделаю текст в более простой и понятный

```
import keyboard
print(“start”)
keyboard.wait(!!!“ctrl” or “shift”!!!)
print(“end”)
```

задача кода- дождаться пока будет нажата ИЛИ ctrl ИЛИ shift(приведённый вариант ниже с `or`  не рабочий, функция будет ждать ответ только о нажатие crtl). как это можно сделать с помощью этого пакета. Можно предложить другой пакет или альтернативный выход из ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Берем Dec коды клавиатуры - https://narvell.nl/keys

И инициализируем свой хук:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import ctypes
import win32con
import win32api
import win32gui
import atexit

KeyboardEvent = namedtuple('KeyboardEvent', ['event_type', 'key_code'])

event_types = {win32con.WM_KEYDOWN: 'key down',
                   win32con.WM_KEYUP: 'key up',
                   0x104: 'key down',  # WM_SYSKEYDOWN, used for Alt key.
                   0x105: 'key up',  # WM_SYSKEYUP, used for Alt key.
                   }

handlers = []

def listen():
    
    def low_level_handler(nCode, wParam, lParam):
        lParam = ctypes.cast(lParam, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)).contents.value
        event = KeyboardEvent(event_types[wParam], lParam)
        
        for handler in handlers:
            handler(event)

        return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)

    CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (
        ctypes.c_int,
        CMPFUNC,
        ctypes.c_void_p,
        ctypes.c_uint
    )
    pointer = CMPFUNC(low_level_handler)

    hook_id = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, pointer,
                                                     win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)

    atexit.register(ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, hook_id)

    win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def print_event(event):
        
        if event.key_code == 160 or event.key_code == 162:
            print("Нажат ctrl ИЛИ shift:", event)

    handlers.append(print_event)
    listen()
```

Примеры моих извращений на тему хуков: https://gist.github.com/Amgarak/5df8477bad67dabbc491322e74ce1c2c

Более простой пример:

```
while True:
    # Wait for the next event.
    event = keyboard.read_event()
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN and (event.name == 'ctrl' or event.name == 'shift'):
        print('Ап!')
```

Comment: Не очень кроссплатформенно

Comment: Логично, вин32 как бы намекает.

Comment: либо это не мой уровень, либо это не то что мне нужно. думаю это можно решить более лёгким способом

Comment: @kzyka дополнил ответ, посмотрите еще вариант с keyboard.read_event ()

Comment: благодарю. когда вернусь к проекту, подробно вникну и добавлю :)

Answer (score -2):

В wait нельзя, но можно использовать другую функцию.

Python 3:

```
import keyboard

def start():
    global exit 
    exit = True


def main():
    keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+p', start, suppress=True, trigger_on_release=True)
    while not exit:
        # Делаем всякое, пока не нажали alt+p.
    keyboard.remove_hotkey('alt+p')
```

Вместо start можно и print по нажатию вызвать, например:

```
import keyboard
def main():
    keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+p', print, args=('hello', 'hotkey'))
```

```
output: "hello hotkey"
```

Comment: А в `start` не нужно `exit` как `global` описать? Без этого ошибка по идее будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf а `false` и `true` вас значит не смущают )

Comment: @andreymal Не, я сам всё время путаю какие в `C#`, а какие в `Python`, где большие, но по 5, а где маленькие, но по 3 )

Comment: @andreymal поправил

Comment: @CrazyElf поправил

Comment: Тьфу, то есть не ошибка будет, а просто `exit` будет локальной переменной функции, которая ни на что не влияет. Вот если сначала попытаться прочитать переменную, а потом в неё что-то записать - тогда будет ошибка.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH `global` переменную нужно внутри функции объявлять, снаружи по идее без толку это делать.

Comment: А вы всё ленитесь попробовать запустить свой код

Comment: @andreymal Да уж, теперь инициализация переменной `exit` пропала, безобразие ))